# Read text file with ImmutableOrderedMultiDict and parse in python as dict

Tags: python

I currently have a text file full of lines with the following data

```
ImmutableOrderedMultiDict([('txn_type', u'subscr_signu'), ('subscr_id', u'123123'), ('last_name', u'nar'), ('residence_country', u'US'), ('mc_currency', u'USD'), ('item_name', u'Upgrade'), ('business', u'example@example.com'), ('amount3', u'5.00'), ('recurring', u'1'), ('verify_sign', u'asdfasdddd'), ('payer_status', u'verified'), ('test_ipn', u'1'), ('payer_email', u'john@example.com'), ('first_name', u'John'), ('receiver_email', u'email@example.com'), ('payer_id', u'1N1nn'), ('reattempt', u'1'), ('charset', u'windows-1252'), ('notify_version', u'3.8'), ('period3', u'1 M'), ('mc_amount3', u'5.00'), ('ipn_track_id', u'123111111111')])
```

This is in `out.txt` I'm trying to have my python program print the `txn_type` but keep getting 
`TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

```
from werkzeug.datastructures import ImmutableOrderedMultiDict
lines = []

with open("out.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            lines.append(line)
        except:
            pass

for i in lines:
    print(i['txn_type'])
    break
```

Comment: Yeah your text is just text. Reading it in will result in a `str`, not whatever data structure is represented by the string. Also, why the `try ... except` for appending to lines? Anyway, that whole thing could replaced by `lines = f.readlines()`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga so is there anyway to convert it to what it is instead of a string?

Comment: You're solving the problem at the wrong end; why is it serialised like that to start with?

Comment: @jonrsharpe exactly. someone should have used `pickle`. Nevertheless, you could just use `eval`, if you trust the source. It is a hack and inherently unsafe if you don't trust the source.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was about to also give the hint to use `eval` (with the necessary caution) but this need not work. The constructor of `ImmutableOrderedMultiDict` must be able to work on such a list. That's probable but not automatic.

Comment: @mkiever we can only speculate.

Comment: `eval` seems to do the trick

Comment: please dont use `eval`, it's totally unsafe thing to do.

Comment: a generic advice - store the data in the file as something else, for example `json`. Then load the data via `json.loads()`

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko You could parse out the list inside the constructor and then do something like `ImmutableOrderedMultiDict(ast.literal_eval(parsed))` to try to be safer about it. Regardless, as you've implied, and as jonrsharpe explicitly stated, this is a problem being solved at the wrong end. The data should be serialized some other way (`JSON`, `pickle` etc). However, sometimes people don't have the luxury to change something like that and are being left to clean up someone else mess.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, its my mess I'm trying to clean up given that this was code I wrote a couple years ago when I first got started.

Answer (score 0):

As posted in the comments by @juanpa.arrivillaga suggested the `eval` did the trick